# Вывести уникальные неповторяющиеся строки

Tags: linux, bash, сортировка, grep, diff

Есть два файла

Содержимое первого:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Содержимое второго:

```
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Нужно сравнить два файла и вывести только уникальные строки, т.е. только три последние строки из второго файла.

Перебрал уже множество утилит типа sort comm diff uniq и не одна не предоставила требуемый результат.

Comment: А 1 и 2 это не уникальные строки? Их ведь нет во втором файле.

Comment: Судя по задаче нужны строки из второго файла которых нет в первом

Comment: `diff` не помог?

Comment: @de_frag думаю вопрос поставлен не корректно поэтому автор путается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Нужно сравнить два файла и вывести только уникальные строки, т.е. только три последние строки из второго файла.

первая часть предложения противоречит второй. уникальных строк будет пять (включая две первые строки из первого файла).

просто уникальные строки (первая часть предложения):

```
$ sort -u файл1 файл2
```

уникальные строки только из второго файла (вторая часть предложения):

```
$ comm -1 -3 файл1 файл2
```

опция `-1` исключит уникальные для первого файла строки, опция `-3` — общие для двух файлов строки. для корректной работы программы *comm* файлы должны быть отсортированы.

---

доп. чтение:

- `$ info sort` (если установлена программа *info*) или `$ man sort`
- `$ info comm` (если установлена программа *info*) или `$ man comm`

Comment: Почему то не работает ...

Comment: Условие, если в двух файлах имеются одинаковые строки то не нужно их показывать.

Comment: так это уже третий вопрос. посмотрите наконец `$ man comm` или прочитайте наконец ответ (в нём ключевая информация про смысл опций — указана).

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
grep -vx "$(<file_1)" file_2 | sort -u
```

Answer (score 1):

`cat file1 file2 |sort |uniq -u`

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае все дело оказалось в неверном формате конца строки одного из файлов.
Один был в LF (unix) а второй CRLF (windows) из за этого команда сравнения не отрабатывала вообще ни как.
Итоговый вариант который подходит именно мне cat 1.txt 2.txt|sort|uniq -u
Вариант с comm то же отлично работает.
Всем спасибо!